# I need help to spot the difference from the code I need to find why my code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Please see below both the code and help to understand what happened in my code that my code is not working.

first code is written by me but it is not working and second the correct one is copied code. I was looking from last 2 hours but I didn't get any findings.

```
<!-- mycode -->
 <script>

    function removeTransition(e){
        if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
       e.target.classList.remove('playing');  
         
        }

     function playSound(e){
     const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
     const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

       if(!audio) return; //stop the function from running all together.
        audio.currentTime = 0; //Rewind to the start.
        audio.play();
        key.classList.add('playing');
    }
    
    const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
    keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitioned', removeTransition));

    window.addEventListener('keydown',playSound);
</script>


<!-- correct code -->
<script>
  function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
    
  }

  function playSound(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return;

    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add('playing');
  }

  const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
  keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
</script>
```

Comment: Please describe: "_but it is not working_"

Comment: Check the browser console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Is that the fix or no?

Answer (score 0):

It's the word `transitioned` vs `transitionend`

```
//your code
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitioned', removeTransition));

//correct code
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

Other than that, there are only minor spacing differences between the two.